# TYPO3 CMS 8.7 Jquery errors after moving site

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x

Recently I've moved one of my development sites into production.
The following steps were taken.

- Complete backup of both versions (4.5 & 8.7)
- Removal of old version
- Uploading new TYPO3 developed version
- Updating database connection in the LocalConfiguration file

After doing all this and enabling the install tool I am able to login to my install tool but not into the backed. Both the install tool and the backend are giving the following error.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` on Jquery. Various other errors also appear because of this. Included below is a screenshot for completion.

[image]

No file transfers failed and I am unable to login to the backend. I haven't done anyhthing to the database apart from setting it up

Comment: Open `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` and look if something is odd there.

Comment: @GhostGambler I've looked there and deleted the file as well, when a new one was obtained it stil gave me the same error

Comment: Did you cleared the caches? Deactivated all extensions? Checked the setup in the Install Toolß

Comment: You mean before movement? Or after the fact? I did clear the caches, but I didn't deactive any extensions. What should I lookout for in the install tool

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that file-compression was activated for JS- and CSS files which doesn't match the settings on the new server.
If you click in the browser-console on a file-link you get some output like this:

[image: debug of compressed file in browser-console]

You can adjust the compression-level in install-tool but can see the value in the file `typo3conf/localconf.php` (for TYPO3 4.x) or `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` (for TYPO3 8).
It might currently look like this:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] = '9';
```

and you can adjust it just to 0:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['BE']['compressionLevel'] = '0';
```

In the install-tool of TYPO3 4.5 the option looks like this:

[image: compressionLevel in install-tool]

Answer (score 0):

The problems comes from the setup.ts or config file. Comment / uncomment these lines until it will work. Is usually the compression of js that is the problem:

```
#config.concatenateCss = 1
#config.compressCss = 1
#config.concatenateJs = 1
#config.compressJs =1
```